# Flutter and Dart -> add path on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: flutter, dart, path

I am trying to add flutter to the path but no solution is working for me right now. It was working before when I installed it from snap. Now I am cloning flutter repo into the `opt` folder and No matter what I try, flutter is not working. I am using ZSH terminal.
So far I have tried:

1. Adding `export PATH=~/opt/flutter/bin:$PATH` on last line of .zshrc and .bashrc file.
2. Running `export PATH="$PATH:~/opt/flutter/bin"` on the terminal.

And bunch of other tweaks on the keywords but none of the things seems to work.

Comment: `~/opt` means a directory named `opt` that's in your home directory.  Is that really what you mean, or did you mean a system-wide `/opt` directory?  Also, changes to your rc files won't take effect immediately; you need to start a new shell prices or reload them in your current shell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you mean you have cloned flutter to /opt folder

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/flutter/bin"
```

Also if you doesn't mean that and you solely mean ~/opt folder then first verify your flutter installation by typing
`~/opt/flutter/bin/flutter`
in your terminal,
It should launch flutter it your terminal if not then either your installation is broken or you have to type
`chmod +x -R ~/opt/flutter/bin` 
to make flutter executable if it's not.

PS: Also don't forget to restart your shell if you haven't cause you have to restart you shell after changing something in your .rc files.

I hope I have helped you if not please comment so that I can improve the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately for me, things didn't go well while flutter was in the opt folder. Right now I have cloned it in the Documents folder and so far everything is working fine. I cannot verify if this works but I did do it while giving the read/write access to the flutter/bin folder but still it was throwing error saying flutter/bin/cache cannot be modified. And command didn't work globally, just when folder was accessed. For now it is working though.

Answer (score 0):

This work on Ubuntu.

Add to file `.profile` the following line:

`export PATH="$PATH:/home/your_user_name/opt/flutter/bin`